# vue.js 2.0 Reset props passed to modal component on close

Tags: forms, vue.js, modal-dialog, vuex, v-model

I have a account component which allows the user to click on the current billing address and a modal opens with a form to update their billing address. The billing address is passed as a prop to the child (modal) component as such

```js
<sweet-modal ref="billingAddressModal" v-on:close="test">
  <BillingAddressForm :billingAddress="currentCustomer">       </BillingAddressForm>
 </sweet-modal>
```

If the user edits the any field but then decides to close the modal and then reopen it the edits are persisted. What is the correct approach to reset it to the original values as I only want to update the address if they submit the form?

```html
<form v-on:submit.prevent class="billingAddressForm">
  <div class="grid__item text-left">
    <label>Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item large-up--one-half">
    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" v-model="cachedUser.first_name" />
  </div>
  ... ...
</form>
```

Parent Component JS

```js
  import {
    mapState,
    mapGetters
  } from 'vuex'
import {
  SweetModal
} from 'sweet-modal-vue'
import CardForm from './CardForm'
import BillingAddressForm from './BillingAddressForm'

export default {
  components: {
    SweetModal,
    CardForm,
    BillingAddressForm
  },
  data() {
    return {
      title: 'order history'
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'currentCustomer'
    ])
  },
  methods: {
    openCardUpdateModal() {
      this.$refs.cardModal.open()
    },
    openBillingAddressModal() {
      this.$refs.billingAddressModal.open()
    },
    test() {
      alert(this.currentCustomer = null)
    }
  }
};
```

Child Component JS

```js
export default {
  name: 'BillingAddressForm',
  props: {
    billingAddress: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: You'll have to paste way more code. Show the JavaScript for the component and for its parent component.

Answer (score 1):

```js
<sweet-modal ref="billingAddressModal" v-on:close="onClose">
  <BillingAddressForm :billingAddress="currentCustomer">       </BillingAddressForm>
 </sweet-modal>
```

You can have a mutation called onClose which set everything to null when called.

```
onClose(){
   this.billingAddress = null
}
```

Comment: the onClose handler is on the parent component so this.billingAddress wouldn't be accessible at the parent?

Comment: Child can communicate with parents by `$emit`, but as you are using vuex, you  can user a mutation for that.